# Windows Virtual Desktop Max Disconnection Time

Tags: windows, azure, virtualization, virtual-machines

We created some new virtual desktop pools on azure.
Now we want to configure that every session which is disconnected ends immediately.

We configured this registry key:

Registry Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Subkey: \Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\
Value Name: MaxDisconnectionTime
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 0x0000ea60 (60000)

Sadly we still have a lot of disconnected sessions :(
Could anyone help us?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify the registry on your Master Image (if you used a custom image to create WVD pool) or the registry of the WVD created already & set this value on the rdp listener

The sessions which will connect after the below value is added would be logged off after 1 minute of disconnection

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp
Value Name: MaxDisconnectionTime Type: REG_DWORD Value: 0x0000ea60 (60000)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the registry entry suggested by Nitish Dhiman, you can also use the group policies located under either of the following locations.

```
Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Session Time Limits

User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Session Time Limits
```

In particular the [Set time limit for disconnected sessions](https://getadmx.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.TerminalServer::TS_SESSIONS_Disconnected_Timeout_2) policy.